# Композиция чисел с нулями(и с ограничениями)

Tags: python, комбинаторика

я хочу получить композицию числа с нулями и ограничениями, т.е. изначально есть список с ограничениями на максимум, например `[5,3,4]` будет означать что в композиции должно быть минимум 3 числа(нули возможны), и что первое не может быть больше 5и, второе не может быть больше 3ех, третье больше 4ех. И дано число 8 которое, соответственно, по этим правилам надо разложить.
Подскажите где подобные примеры алгоритмов можно найти или каким образом можно реализовать такое.

Comment: Нафига тут алгоритм? Сперва для проверки суммируешь верхние границы, если они меньше числа - облом. Иначе тупо считаешь, сколько лишнего, и начинаешь отнимать (да прям по порядку). Если остаток больше очередного числа-границы, отнимаем сколько можем (до нуля) и переходим к следующему. По примеру. 5+3+4=12>8, нормально. Избыток 12-8=4. Отнимаем от первого эти 4, и получаем композицию {1,3,4}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекурсивно проходим по каждому уровню, ограничивая слагаемые:

```
def compo(n, limits, res):
    if len(limits) == 0:
        if n == 0:
            print(res)
        return
    for i in range(limits[0] + 1):
        compo(n - i, limits[1:], res + str(i) + " ")

compo(8, [5,3,4], "")

1 3 4 
2 2 4 
2 3 3 
3 1 4 
3 2 3 
3 3 2 
4 0 4 
4 1 3 
4 2 2 
4 3 1 
5 0 3 
5 1 2 
5 2 1 
5 3 0
```

Comment: а не подскажете, можно ли такую схему перенести на список списков, т.е. на выходе получить список списков. Т.е. что-то вроде этого(только этот работает некорректно): fulllst=[] per1=[3, 3, 4, 2, 1] z=5 xlst=[0]*z def col(n, point): global xlst if point == 4: if n == 0: fulllst.append(xlst) xlst=[0]*z return for i in range(per1[point]+1): xlst[point+1]=i col(n - i, point + 1) col(z,0) print(fulllst)

Comment: Вместо строк получить списки? Да, возможно, но как это сделать наилучшим образом - подскажут специалисты по Python. Я бы перед рекурсивным вызовом добавлял к списку элемент `i`, после вызова удалял, а если этот список списков нужно как-то использовать, то вместо print делал deepcopy (или просто [c for c in res_list])